# SQLite, insert variable in my table (c# console app)

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sql-server, sqlite

```
string TheName = "David";
string UserTable = "INSERT INTO USER (name) values (TheName)";
SQLiteCommand command2 = new SQLiteCommand(UserTable, m_dbConnection);
command2.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

I was wondering if it is possible to insert a variable in my SQLite table (like the TheName in the example code) , and if it is how are you able to do it ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need parameterized queries:

```
command2.CommandText = "INSERT INTO User (name) VALUES(@param1)";
command2.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
command2.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@param1", TheName));
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a parameterized query:

```
string UserTable = "INSERT INTO USER (name) values ($TheName)";
command2.Parameters.AddWithValue("$TheName", TheName);
```

http://johnhforrest.com/2010/10/parameterized-sql-queries-in-c/